# sapa R package fails to install with R Studio Version 2023.03.1+446

Tags: r, installation, package, cran

Background: I recently updated to R Studio version 2023.03.1+446.  (I am using R version 4.3.0 running on Ubuntu 20.04.)  As a result, I had to reload a number of packages that I'm using in my research.  One of the packages I've been using in my research is the fractal package.

Problem:  In the process of re-loading all the dependencies for the fractal package, I was not able to successfully load the sapa package (sapa = Spectral Analysis for Physical Applications).  (I previously successfully installed it for R Studio version 2022.07.1+554.)

I get the following messages when attempting to install sapa from the tar file downloaded from the CRAN repository.  Any ideas or help on the cause of the install failure would be greatly appreciated.

```
    > install.packages("/home/alanj/Downloads/sapa_2.0-3.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
    Installing package into ‘/home/alanj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    * installing *source* package ‘sapa’ ...
    ** package ‘sapa’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** using staged installation
    ** libs
    using C compiler: ‘gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0’
    gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG       -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-      dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c sapa_lapack.c -o sapa_lapack.o
    In file included from /usr/share/R/include/R.h:78,
                 from sapa_lapack.c:1:
    sapa_lapack.c: In function ‘R_sapa_dpss’:
    sapa_lapack.c:87:12: error: too few arguments to function ‘dstebz_’
   87 |   F77_CALL(dstebz)(
      |            ^~~~~~
   /usr/share/R/include/R_ext/RS.h:77:22: note: in definition of macro ‘F77_CALL’
   77 | # define F77_CALL(x) x ## _
      |                      ^
   /usr/share/R/include/R_ext/Lapack.h:1161:10: note: declared here
   1161 | F77_NAME(dstebz)(const char* range, const char* order, const int* n,
      |          ^~~~~~
   /usr/share/R/include/R_ext/RS.h:77:22: note: in definition of macro ‘F77_CALL’
   77 | # define F77_CALL(x) x ## _
      |                      ^
   /usr/share/R/include/R_ext/Lapack.h:1161:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘F77_NAME’
   1161 | F77_NAME(dstebz)(const char* range, const char* order, const int* n,
      | ^~~~~~~~
   make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:191: sapa_lapack.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sapa’
   * removing ‘/home/alanj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/sapa’
   Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘/home/alanj/Downloads/sapa_2.0-3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
> `
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!   While I unfamiliar with the `sapa` package itself, the error suggests this is due to the somewhat recent changes in R regarding `FC_LEN` and a tightening / cleanup of Fortran interfaces with char variables.  You could contact the package author, or try fixing it yourself.  Between _Writing R Extensions_ and different threads on the r-package-devel list you may get sufficient help.  If there is a `git` repo for `sapa`, please add it to your question.

Comment: (And to add / clarify the obvious: RStudio has precisely zero to do with any of this. The relevant information comprises your R version (R 4.3.0, good) and your OS release (Ubuntu 20.04).  What you use to launch R is orthogonal to this installation issue.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I wondered if the Ubuntu Fortran libraries might be part of the problem.  Since I still had the problem after making sure those libraries were up to date, my next step will be to update my Ubuntu release and see if that fixes the problem.  I will update my comment with what I discover.

Comment: No. This is purely an R issue. Read up on `FC_LEN`.

Comment: Attempting to contact one of the two maintainers/authors of the package and related packages.  Found one of the two persons by name on LinkedIn.  Waiting for response or other leads.

Comment: Documentation for sapa package located at:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sapa/versions/2.0-3.

Comment: Documentation for fractal package located at: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fractal/versions/2.0-4

Comment: R command to install sapa:  devtools::install_github("wconstan/sapa")
Location:  GitHub repo wconstan/sapa@HEAD

Comment: Maintainer completed update of packages in github.  All the related packages including sapa can be loaded using the following commands: install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
devtools::install_github("spkaluzny/ifultools")
library("ifultools")
devtools::install_github("dbpercival/sapa")
library("sapa")
devtools::install_github("wconstan/wmtsa")
library("wmtsa")
devtools::install_github("wconstan/fractal")
library("fractal")